# Java Method create datapoint node in the container of XML

Tags: java, spring, xsd, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

how to fetch elements of container from XSD by XPath.

Comment: This code won't even compile because Java variables cannot start with a number, you've got the keyword `return` with an upper case `R`, you have case issues with many variables and methods, and multiple curly bracket mismatches.  We can't help you if you're not going to put a bit of effort into this.

Comment: Please indent your code, and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: My Apologies let me fix it really quick.

Comment: Please add the code again, properly formated, if you want anybody to be able to help you